# Make single column into multiple columns based on another column

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a tidy data frame, with one term and topic per row. It looks like this:

```
num_topic, term
1, blue
1, green
2, dog
2, cat
```

I would like to arrange each topic in a separate column, for human readability

```
topic1, topic2
blue, dog
green, cat
```

This seems pretty intuitive, but I cannot figure out how to do it. It is not the same as the linked question, because there are no unique identifiers for each term. There are just lists of terms for each topic.

Comment: This is called a pivot

Comment: Thank you, that's very close! But the problem is, I just want columns of topics. There is really no unique identifier for each term in the topic.

Comment: @Adam_G Can you add a temporary identifier then? e.g. something like `df %>% group_by(num_topic) %>% mutate(id = seq(1, n())) %>% ungroup() %>% spread(num_topic, term) %>% select(-id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following.
Note this assumes that entries per `num_topic` group are "in order", i.e. `blue` belongs to `dog`, `green` belongs to `cat`, and so on.

```
df <- read.csv(text = 
    "num_topic,term
    1,blue
    1,green
    2,dog
    2,cat");

df <- as.data.frame(sapply(split(df, df$num_topic), function(x) x$term));
df;
#       1    2
#1   blue  dog
#2  green  cat
```

Explanation: Split on `num_topic` and bind columns `term` together.

Comment: Or use `unstack(df, term~num_topic)`

Comment: @akrun You win;-) definitely the shortest solution!